# How to generate a file open failure for unit testing

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, ifstream, file-handling

For completeness, I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2012 under Windows 7.

I have some basic file reading code:

Defined in class:

```
std::ifstream iniFileHandle;
```

Method in question:

```
FileLoader::FILE_STATUS FileLoader::loadFile(const std::string& fullpathandfilename)
{
    if (fullpathandfilename.empty())
    {
        iniFileStatus = FILE_NOT_SPECIFIED;
    }
    else // parameter has 'something'...
    {
        if (!doesFileExist(fullpathandfilename))
        {
            iniFileStatus = FILE_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        else // file found...
        {
            iniFileHandle.open(fullpathandfilename, std::ios::in);

            if (!iniFileHandle.is_open()) // something went wrong
            {
                iniFileStatus = FILE_CANNOT_LOAD; // <== HOW TO TEST?
            }
            else // file opened!
            {
                iniFileStatus = FILE_OPEN;
            }
        }
    }

    return iniFileStatus;
}
```

All this works fine but I'm having difficulty getting coverage with Google Unit Tests.

What i'm missing is a way to simulate/create a scenario where `is_open()` fails.

I've tried:

- read only files
- the 'exe' being currently run
- a file opened in another application
  but they all open.

Is this error condition actually possible to occur? If so, how can I mimic the failure so I can test it?

Comment: Have you tried opening a directory for reading? This should cause an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, trying to open a directory will cause is_open() to return `false`. The cases you tried all succeed because you open the file as read-only (`std::ios::in`, which is also the default for an `ifstream`).

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried:
>
> a file opened in another application but they all open.

This happens because file is opened in share mode which allows reading for others. You need to open file in exclusive file access mode. To achieve it, if you use MSVS, you could pass the third parameter `int _Prot` to the [ifstream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8473817e-42a4-430b-82b8-b476c86bcf8a.aspx#basic_fstream__basic_fstream), otherwise you could use  [CreateFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx).

To emulate the problem you could open file exclusively used by Windows, e.g:

```
c:\pagefile.sys
```

Answer (score 0):

create a any file, and set its permission as read only, and in your code try to open this file for writing